# Android DatePicker listener not triggering

Tags: android, datepicker, listener

I'm using the DatePicker widget and I can't seem to get the listener to trigger, I've put logs everywhere to see what is happening but it just doesn't seem to realise that the date has changed

Main.java

```
DatePicker dp = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
dp.init(year, month, day, new OnDateChangedListener (){
    public void onDateChanged(DatePicker dp, int selectedYear, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
    {
        year = selectedYear;
        month = monthOfYear;
        day = dayOfMonth;
        updateTime(year, month, day);
    };
}); // setup initial values and reg. handler
```

Here is my section in xml just for good measure

```
<DatePicker 
    android:id="@+id/datePicker" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:padding="5sp" 
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</DatePicker>
```

Comment: I have same problem. I think that is because of your android version. I have tested the code on 2 different devices which one is 21. other one is 23. onDateChanged is called on second one. And I found the reason :( https://stackoverflow.com/a/31611665/4606266

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DatePicker dp = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
dp.init(year, month, day,datepickerListener);
```

and in your `DatePickerListener` add this code

private DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener datepickerListener= new OnDateChangedListener (){

```
@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth){
    if (view.isShown()) {
        dp.set(selectedYear, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
    }
}
```

Comment: dp.set won't resolve. Can't seem to find it in the method list

Answer (score 0):

**@Brendon Rother** , Try this way .Let me inform

```
// the date picker listener
OnDateChangedListener birthdayListener = new OnDateChangedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDateChanged(DatePicker birthDayDatePicker,
                              int newYear, int newMonth, int newDay) {

        try
        {
            // currentMonth + 1, to retrieve proper month
            setHumanReadableDate(newYear, newMonth + 1, newDay);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
```

Demo [Android Date Picker Example App](https://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/08/android-date-picker-example.html)