# DatePicker with Databinding and Rxjava Observable view does not save to Realm on different Android Versions

Tags: datepicker, realm, rx-java, observable, android-databinding

The codes below runs in an android emulator with Android version SDK 16. But somehow when it runs on the emulator with Android version >21, DataBinding and Realm savings doesn't get triggered..

How should I be dealing with Android versioning?

Is it because the rendered UI differs in different android versions so DataBinding wouldn't have worked either?

This code here is the ViewModel

```
@PerFragment
public class OnboardDOBViewModel extends BaseHelperViewModel<BaseUserView> implements IOnboardDOBViewModel {

private String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();
private HelperRepo mHelperRepo;
private UserRepo mUserRepo;
private Helper mHelper;

public final ObservableField<Integer> datePicker = new ObservableField<>();
public final ObservableField<Integer> monthPicker = new ObservableField<>();
public final ObservableField<Integer> yearPicker = new ObservableField<>();

public ReadOnlyField dobSelected;

private CompositeDisposable mCompositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();

@Inject
public OnboardDOBViewModel(@AppContext Context context, UserRepo userRepo, HelperRepo helperRepo) {
    super(context, userRepo, helperRepo);
    Log.d(TAG, "OnboardDOBViewModel: ");
    this.mUserRepo = userRepo;
    this.mHelperRepo = helperRepo;
}

@Override
public void attachView(BaseUserView view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.attachView(view, savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(TAG, "attachView");

    mHelper = mHelperRepo.getByUser("user.id", mUserRepo.getCurrentUser(), false);

    if (mHelper != null) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        yearPicker.set(c.get(Calendar.YEAR)-23);
        monthPicker.set(c.get(Calendar.MONTH));
        datePicker.set(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    }

    Observable<String> dobSelected = Observable.combineLatest(
            Utils.toObservable(monthPicker),
            Utils.toObservable(datePicker),
            Utils.toObservable(yearPicker),
            (integer, integer2, integer3) -> {

                String dobSelected1 = String.valueOf(monthPicker.get() + 1) + "-" +
                        datePicker.get().toString() + "-" +
                        yearPicker.get().toString();
                Log.d(TAG, "apply: " + dobSelected1);
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
                Date date = sdf.parse(dobSelected1);
                Log.d(TAG, "apply: date selected" + date);

                Helper helper = mHelperRepo.getByUser("user.id", mUserRepo.getCurrentUser(), true);
                assert helper != null;
                helper.setDateOfBirth(date);
                mHelperRepo.save(helper);
                return dobSelected1;
            });

    this.dobSelected = Utils.toField(dobSelected);
}
```

This is the XML

```
<data>

    <variable
        name="vm"
        type="...OnboardDOBViewModel" />
</data>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="30dp"
        android:text="@string/toolbar_title_date_of_birth"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large" />

    <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/onboard_birth_date_picker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:calendarViewShown="false"
        android:day="@={vm.datePicker}"
        android:month="@={vm.monthPicker}"
        android:solidColor="@color/grayMedium"
        android:spinnersShown="true"
        android:year="@={vm.yearPicker}" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="test"
        android:text="@{vm.dobSelected}"
        android:visibility="visible"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this as my answer

[OnDateChanged is not called in Date picker Android lollipop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31609777/ondatechanged-is-not-called-in-date-picker-android-lollipop)

added this in, and override the config, calendar UI is now spinner style and binding works

```
android:datePickerMode="spinner"
```